# why do we need different viewport for shadow map

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow, glm-math

I'm reading [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping) and I noticed that he is using a different viewport to generate the shadow map.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because the framebuffer where the shadow map is rendered to, has a different size than the default framebuffer

Comment: @Rabbid76 but why?

Comment: The point of view of the shadow map is the light source. The field of view has to include all the area which is illuminated by the light and which is "seen" by the current view on the scene. It can have any resolution. Higher resolution results in more accuracy an higher quality. Lower resolution gives a better performance.